# XCode 4: How to show hidden build settings

Tags: xcode

I recently migrated from XCode 3 to XCode 4. I've spent more than one hour trying to find some build setting (Runpath Search Paths) without finding it.

I've come back to XCode 3, opened the same project, and there could find that setting. I set a value, and came back to XCode 4. The build setting has appeared.

It seems like the build settings are by default displayed only if they have a non-default value.

[image: Screenshot of my build settings window]

Is there any way to show all build settings, including the ones with default value?

Comment: switch from **Basic** to **All** ;)

Comment: Skip Xcode 4 and go to Xcode 5; Xcode 6 is almost on us...

Comment: @sage444: How could I miss that? It like the nose on the face! Thank you

Comment: @trojanfoe: I never dared switch to XCode 5 because of some requirements of the software for which I develop plugins. I have just done it, and it works like a charm (for compilation, at least). Thank you

Comment: @RémiDoolaeghe Cool; I don't think there should be too much to worry about, apart from the compiler generally generating more warnings (which are probably valid anyway).